# Node + AngularJs + Socket.io: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io, digital-ocean, socket.io-1.0

I keep getting this error in my browser's console so I think it is an angular + socket.io problem:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LF3gkk7 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Eventho I followed advices which told to change angular var `io` like:

```
ctrl.socketIo = io();
ctrl.socketIo = io.connect();
ctrl.socketIo = io.connect('http://localhost:3001');
```

none of those worked!

This is how my Angular controller looks:

```
angular.module("app")
    .controller("chatController", [
        'userService',
        function (userService) {

            var ctrl = this;
            ctrl.messages = [];

            ctrl.socketIo = io();
            ctrl.userName = userService.name;

            ctrl.submit = function () {

               ctrl.socketIo.emit("chat_message", ctrl.inputMessage);

               ctrl.messages.push(ctrl.inputMessage);           

               ctrl.inputMessage = null;
            };


            ctrl.socketIo.on("update_clients", function (msg) {

                ctrl.messages.push(msg);

            });

         }]
     );
```

My index.html path are pointing to the dirs:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 //boilerplate...
</head>

<body ng-app="app">

 //boilerplate...

   <script src="/bower_components/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>

//boilerplate...

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see in my dir structure path is pointing correctly to socket.io.js:

[image]

## Update

I'm using Digital ocean VPS, and when I run `netstat -a -p` there does NOT seem that PORT 3000 is being used.

## UPdate 2:

One service in my app was trying to connect to localhost:3000 so I erased that part since I don't need socket there now I'm getting:

[image]

## Update 3 back end code:

```
'use strict';

var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http);

//use environment var PORT or 3001
var portNum = 3001;


//route handler
app.get("/", function (req, res) {

    res.sendFile("./index.html", {root: "./client/"});
});

app.use(express.static('./client'));

io.on("connection", function (socket) {

    socket.on("chat_message", function (msg) {

        socket.broadcast.emit('update_clients', msg);

    });
});


server.listen(portNum, function () {
    console.log("listening on port: " + portNum);
});
```

Comment: Is there any port mismatch ? You are using port `3000` and `3001`.

Comment: @MukeshSharma, I'm using on node side: `var portNum = process.env.PORT || 3001;` I'm also using digital ocean VPS when i call `netstat -a -p`it doesn't seem that PORT 3000 is being used

Comment: You are getting `Connection Refused`, because your backend is listening at port `3001`, your front end app is trying to connect to `3000`.

Comment: ok so there was an angular service pointing to port:3000, now I erased that service since I don't need it anymore and I'm getting the same error but now with `port 3001` (I posted full error on Update 2) in original post

Comment: now, its 404 that means your backend websocket is not working. Can you share backend code ?

Comment: @MukeshSharma, yes I updated with back end code

Comment: @MukeshSharma, thanks to you I discovered, error was changin in app.js of node to `var server = http.Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);` If you want you can include as answer and I'll upvote

Comment: :D I put the answer before your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `404` because your socket.io module was not properly initialized.
Try the following code.

```
'use strict';

var express = require("express");
var app = express(); 
var http = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http);

//use environment var PORT or 3001
var portNum = 3001;


//route handler
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile("./index.html", {root: "./client/"});
});

app.use(express.static('./client'));

io.on("connection", function (socket) {
   socket.on("chat_message", function (msg) {
      socket.broadcast.emit('update_clients', msg);
   });
});


http.listen(portNum, function () {
   console.log("listening on port: " + portNum);
});
```